# Wrong result when recursively count lines with wc

Tags: find, recursive, wc

I am using the following Linux command to recursively count lines of text files in a folders structure:

```
find . -name '*.txt' | xargs -d '\n' wc -l
```

This outputs all found files and their number of lines:

```
  86 ./folder1/folder11/folder111/file1.txt
  67 ./folder1/folder11/folder112/file2.txt
7665 ./folder1/folder11/folder113/file3.txt
..., etc.
1738958 total
```

There are a total of 24k+ files. The number of lines for each file are correct and all files there are possessed. But the total number of lines is not correct.
Even for a sub-folder of this structure the total number of lines is much bigger. For example:

```
cd folder1/folder11
find . -name '*.txt' | xargs -d '\n' wc -l
```

gives at the end 23M lines:

```
22535346 total
```

The total number of all lines should be > 100M, not 1.7M. What I am missing here?

Comment: Are there some other "total" lines that appear part-way through the output?

Comment: Yes, this is the issue. There is not a global total but several local totals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have GNU `wc`, use

```
find . -name "*.txt" -print0 | wc -l --files0-from -
```

The [manual section for this option](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/wc-invocation.html#index-_002d_002dfiles0_002dfrom_003dfile) explains why what you were doing doesn't work:

> `‘--files0-from=file’`
>
> Disallow processing files named on the command line, and instead process those named in file *file*; each name being terminated by a zero byte (ASCII NUL). This is useful when the list of file names is so long that it may exceed a command line length limitation. In such cases, running `wc` via `xargs` is undesirable because it splits the list into pieces and makes `wc` print a total for each sublist rather than for the entire list. One way to produce a list of ASCII NUL terminated file names is with GNU `find`, using its `-print0` predicate. If *file* is ‘-’ then the ASCII NUL terminated file names are read from standard input.

If your `wc` doesn't support this option, you could instead send the output through a simple script to extract all the "total" lines and add them up.

```
... | awk '$2=="total"{t=t+$1} END{print t " total"}'
```

Comment: Now I know that the corpus has 64027131. This same count was return by your solution and the one of Kusalananda.

Comment: i've done that `wc | awk` totalling thing many times over the years, but there *is* a small problem with it.  `wc` provides no way to distinguish between actual totals and files called total - if there are any files called `total`, their lines will be counted twice.    both  `--files0-from` and kusalananda's `-exec cat ...` method work great, though.  the former is good if you want a line count for each file as well as a total, cat if you only care about the final total.

Comment: In my tests, `find .` prints `./total` for a file named `total`, and that's enough for `awk` to distinguish the genuine total.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have so many files, what is happening is, I presume, that `wc -l` is being run on batches on the files by `xargs`.  This is essentially what `xargs` is for; a single invocation of `wc -l` on all the files at once would not work as the command would be too big.  The result that you are seeing is for the *last batch*.  If you scroll up a few thousand lines or so, you will eventually see the result for the previous batch.

If you're just after the total number of lines in all the files, you can `cat` them all and send that data to `wc -l`:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec cat {} + | wc -l
```

This would execute `cat` on batches of found files, and then pass the resulting data stream to `wc -l`.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution is working well and what you say is exactly what is happening. There were several local totals. I have accepted JigglyNaga answer since chronologically he was first.